# Sanitizing SQL query parameters in AWS Athena

Tags: sql-injection, amazon-athena

In AWS Athena, there doesn't appear to be a good way to pass parameters into the SQL query. The typical way to execute is from a `boto3` [call](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution),

```
response = client.start_query_execution(
    QueryString='string',
    ClientRequestToken='string',
    QueryExecutionContext={
        'Database': 'string'
    },
    ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': 'string',
        'EncryptionConfiguration': {
            'EncryptionOption': 'SSE_S3'|'SSE_KMS'|'CSE_KMS',
            'KmsKey': 'string'
        }
    }
)
```

If I need to pass parameters to the QueryString, I need to sanitize it to avoid injection attacks. How do I clean the input?

Comment: To those who closed it - please explain why. It seems perfectly legit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve SQL injection for Athena?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823715/how-to-solve-sql-injection-for-athena)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>There is no such functionality in the Athena API.</strike> Athena now has [prepared statements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-with-prepared-statements.html).